# Honda Civic Radio code reset

Tags: honda

If I disconnect my battery again will I get  more attempts at my radio code ? I bought a  Honda Civic and the battery had to be changed

Comment: What year is your Civic? After disconnecting the battery, I've had to reset the radio in a '92 Accord by procuring the radio serial number from the sticker on the back, and looking up the reset code [using Honda's serial number database](https://radio-navicode.honda.com/).

Comment: 2003, I called a Honda dealer and they said bring it in and we will do it for free, Even if you are locked out

Comment: This site claims to do it given the serial number: https://hondaradiocodes.com/

Answer (score 1):

Like Jim said in the comments, you have to bring it to a Honda dealer and they will reset it for free. Be sure to write the 4 or 5-digit code they give you in the owner’s manual.

Comment: You do not "have" to take it to honda, It is simply one of many options available to retrieve the code.